# Created by field is showing nothing

Tags: item

I am facing a interesting issue in SharePoint Online: when I view detail of a list item, it's created by field is showing blank.

This is how I see it:

[image]

What could be the possible reason? How can I find who created that item?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I have a list that allow anonymous users to add itens. So if the user was not authenticated and he can add itens the information of `Created By` and `Modified By` will not be shown by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another post/thread on this site that talks about this...
[Users cant see 'Modified By' or 'Created By' (columns blank)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75348/users-cant-see-modified-by-or-created-by-columns-blank)